# Why does MSYS2 git try to create ORIG_HEAD.lock in a nonsensical directory?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-pull, msys, msys2

I'm using SourceTree which delegates to MSYS2 git to do a pull. The full output shows the following:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch upstream

git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false pull --rebase upstream master
From https://github.com/metaeducation/ren-c
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD


First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...

fatal: Unable to create 'D:/dev/projects-open-source/ren-c_asampal/D:/dev/projects-open-source/ren-c_asampal/.git/ORIG_HEAD.lock': No such file or directory

Fast-forwarded HEAD to eb5e8acb29f315453d1ec58514acd8c25e1633eb.


git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false submodule update --init --recursive
Completed successfully.
```

Where should I be looking to find the reason for the bogus concatenation when creating the lock file?

I'm using MSYS2/MinGW-w64 under Windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: You should use either strace.exe (comes with MSYS2) or procmon.exe to diagnose this futher. Please report what you find at https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/issues

Comment: Did you use the msys2-based git 2.6.1? https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases